Filling in NULL values from a column with data in another lookup table
I'm building a report on SSRS that is looking to use a parameter @Referrals that gives the description of each coded value within the parameter. There is a data table that shows the list of referrals (tbl.referrals) with a column labelled ReferralSource which display the referrals given ID for each referral.
There are 2 separate lookup tables;

Referrals from investors (tbl.companyinvest [B1-B9])
Referrals from our company (tbl.company [A1-A9])

Both of these tables have 2 columns, Code - The ID of the referrer and Description - The name of the referrer.
If I do a SELECT statement from the table looking at referrals from our company and company investors, I would do;
SELECT R.ReferralSource AS Source
, CI.Description
FROM tbl.referrals AS R                                                             
LEFT JOIN tbl.company AS C ON C.Code = R.ReferralSource
LEFT JOIN tbl.companyinvest AS CI ON CI.Code = R.ReferralSource

The output of this query would look like this;
|Source | Description
   B8     SCAR MEDICAL GROUP                         
   B9     WISEMAN
   A1     NULL
   A7     NULL
   A8     NULL

How can I add the values of tbl.company into the Description column so that the output of the query would look like;
|Source | Description
   B8     SCAR MEDICAL GROUP                         
   B9     WISEMAN
   A1     INTERNAL HR
   A7     INTERNAL MARKETING
   A8     INTERNAL OFFICE

If I use COALESCE(CI.[Description], C.[Description]) AS [Description] or ISNULL(CI.[Description], C.[Description]) then all the values from tbl.companyinvest still appear however only the first value in tbl.company replaces all the NULL values;
|Source | Description
   B8     SCAR MEDICAL GROUP                         
   B9     WISEMAN
   A1     INTERNAL HR
   A7     INTERNAL HR
   A8     INTERNAL HR


What you state is happening and what you describe your data to conflict.

I can't replicate your problem: db<>fiddle

If the answer below does not help, show samples of you data from each of your three tables (as text).

@sean are you familiar with accepting an answer? Cos you don't appear to have accepted any.

This should do it:
SELECT R.ReferralSource
    , COALESCE(CI.Description, C.Description) Description
FROM tbl.referrals AS R                                                             
LEFT JOIN tbl.company AS C ON C.Code = R.ReferralSource
LEFT JOIN tbl.companyinvest AS CI ON CI.Code = R.ReferralSource

But I see this:

however only the first value in tbl.company replaces all the NULL values;

And that's not how it works. The JOIN still correlates rows, so you'll see the value from the company row that matched in the join. If you're seeing something else, check the data to make sure it has the values you think it does.
See it work here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/yLwNkzj7

And notice the fiddle includes examples for both missing rows and NULL values in the columns, but it works both ways.
